# Bash scripting: detect delimiter after email address, and do branching

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, scripting

I have a set of txt files that I need to parse and insert to MySQL.
I'm trying to write a bash script to sanitise the data, before attempting SQL INSERTs.

Files are often in format:

```
email@address.com:hashed_password
```

In some cases, as in the above example, the delimiter is a colon ':'

- Yay, nice and easy...

However some files use a comma ',' or a semicolon ';' as the delimiter instead.

- Hmm not so easy.

As an example of a more varied file:

```
email@address.com;hashed_password
email@address.co.uk,hashed_password
email@address.fr,hashed_password
```

-- note the varied use of delimiters.

I am attempting to write a bash script that checks each line in the txt files.
For each line, the script should detect which delimiter is in use, and adjust the line accordingly.

I decided to use three colons as the SQL delimiter ':::'. This was because many hashed passwords contained more occurrences of the delimiter.

Here's my original bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="/file/path/location"
for file in "$DIR"/*.txt
do
echo "Processing file $file"
sed -i 's/:/:::/' "$file"
echo "Importing to SQL db"
mysql -uroot -p'password' <<EOF
USE collection1;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file' INTO TABLE test_table CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':::' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
EOF
echo "Import complete, archiving file..."
sudo mv "$file" processed/
done
```

This first attempt worked where files had a colon delimiter, but of course failed to work with files that used a semicolon or comma.

I guess I need some pattern matching? Well, OK then let's get stuck in.

I experimented with some pattern matching as I'm new to it. I ended up with this line:

```
grep -Eio '\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b' test_data.txt
```

Yay, this produced a nice long list of email addresses in my terminal:

```
email@address.net
email@address.com
email@address.fr
etc
```

OK, but I need to detect the delimiter, which follows these email addresses. Well I made a simple addition:

```
grep -Eio '\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b.{0,1}' test_data.txt
```

Another win, this time I get a list of email addresses with the delimiter at the end of each line:

```
email@address.net:
email@address.fr;
email@address.com:
etc
```

But, how can I make a decision/branch, based on what the delimiter is? Am I headed in the right direction with this approach?

What I'll do is:

```
if [ delimiter=":" ] 
    sed -i 's/:/:::/' "$file"
elif [ delimiter =";" ]
    sed -i 's/;/:::/' "$file"
elif [ delimiter ="," ]
    sed -i 's/,/:::/' "$file"
etc
```

I hope this makes sense! Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why bother determining the delimiter? Just allow either delimiter.
Here we replace the first `,`/`;`/`:` we encounter after each `@` with your custom delimiter `:::`

```
sed -i -E 's/(@[^,;:]*)[,;:]/\1:::/' "$file"
```

This is safe even though the local-part (before `@`) [can contain `,`/`,`/`:`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part) when quoted. The domain part (after `@`) can neither contain `,` nor `;`, nor `:`. Since we only look at that part, there are no problems.